# Findin the initial value with matrix exponentiation.

Tags: linear-algebra, ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, self-learning

If I have this:

Suppose I have a matrix:

If I have this:

$$\dfrac{d}{dt} \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix}=\begin{bmatrix}2 & 2 & -2 \\ 5 & 1 & -3 \\ 1 & 5 & -3\end{bmatrix} \begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix}$$

and when $t=0$ $$\begin{bmatrix}x \\ y \\ z\end{bmatrix}= \begin{bmatrix}1 \\ 1 \\ 1\end{bmatrix}$$

And additionaly \begin{align}e^{tA}&=M^{-1}\begin{bmatrix}1&t&\frac{t^2}2\\0&1&t\\0&0&1\end{bmatrix}M\\&=\begin{bmatrix}\frac{1}{2} \left(-t^2+t+2\right) & \frac{1}{16} (t-4) t & -\frac{1}{32}
   (t-2) t \\
 2 t (t+3) & 1-\frac{t^2}{4} & \frac{1}{8} t (t+2) \\
 4 t (3 t+1) & \frac{1}{2} (8-3 t) t & \frac{1}{4} \left(3 t^2-2
   t+4\right)\end{bmatrix}\end{align}

Then how am I supposed to solve this problem when $t=0$.

Do I simply substitute $t=0$ into $\exp\left[tA \right]$ as this appears too obvious?

I also apologise for the mess with matrices, I am relatively new to this forum.

Thank you for any help.

Comment: Please check my edit and see if everything is as you intended. I swapped your $u$ to $t$ because is more common to use t as the independent variable and because $u$ was inconsistent with your exponential, which contained $t$ instead of $u$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have the dynamical system

$$\boldsymbol{\dot{x}}(t) = \boldsymbol{Ax} \qquad ,\quad \boldsymbol{x}(t=t_0)=\boldsymbol{x}_0.$$

Then the general solution is given by

$$\boldsymbol{x}(t) = \exp\left[(t-t_0)\boldsymbol{A} \right]\boldsymbol{x}_0.$$